# visual stadio express 2015 で変数名一覧を取得するには？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

お世話になっております。
作成した変数一覧を確認できれば便利なのですが、
何か方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: visual stadio自体にはそういう機能はないように思います。クロスリファレンスツールを検索してみたらどうでしょうか。

Comment: クロスリファレンスツールですか。
初めて知りました。ありがとうございます。